# jqGrid: What is wrong in my JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to fill my jqGrid with this data:

```
{"total":"1",
 "page":"1",
 "records":"1",
 "rows":[
     {"id":"1", "cell":["1000020","MONT,"1","Data Test", "Lieu en attente", "C", "", "", "", "Data Test"]}
 ]
}
```

But nothing is happening? How to get the error or what is wrong?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A text editor with syntax highlighting would show you that you are missing a `"` after `"MONT`.

```
{"total":"1",
 "page":"1",
 "records":"1",
 "rows":[
     {"id":"1", "cell":["1000020","MONT","1","Data Test", "Lieu en attente", "C", "", "", "", "Data Test"]}
 ]
}
```

You can also use [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate your JSON.

Bear in mind that it's generally better to use a tool to generate your JSON, so that this kind of mistake doesn't happen. Many languages have built-in functions to do this; otherwise, there will probably be a library available to do it.

Comment: How yeah! Awesome tool. Thank you it's ok!

Answer (score 1):

[JSONList](http://jsonlint.com/) says:

```
Parse error on line 5:
...":["1000020","MONT,"1","Data Test", "Lie
-----------------------^
Expecting '}', ':', ',', ']'
```